# How can we add standard item record as sub list of custom record?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I want to add a standard item record as a sub list of my custom record in netsuite. Like we can use item sub list in sales order record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a second **custom record** (it will be a subrecord of your main custom record)

**Main tab**

Allow child record editing = true

First Field creates the link to the parent

1. **Type** is List/Record
2. **List/Record** is *Your main custom record*
3. Record is Parent = true
4. Show in list = true

I would usually set display type to disabled for the linking field.

The add another custom field

1. **Type** is List/Record
2. **List/Record** is *ITEM*
3. Record is Parent = true
4. Show in list = true

Go ahead and add other fields as required for description etc...